# UIVIEW Subclass with UITextViewDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

My view controller was getting complicated so i decided to group some controls together and subclass a uiview. In my view controller i'm grabbing the view:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) PostMenuCell *menuCell;
menuCell = [[PostMenuCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3,200,304,96) ];
menuCell.textView.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:menuCell];
```

And it appears just fine. I have a text view and am using the delegate in the VC as so:

```
@interface PostPictureViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>
```

I'm trying to use the text view delegate methods such as:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView
-(BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range        replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

The keyboard pops up when you click the text area but the delegate methods dont get used so i can't perform any actions or close the keyboard. I thought menuCell.textView.delegate = self; would make the text view delegate the VC but clearly not.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: @shabzco That suggestion doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check if textview isn't nil at the time you set its delegate.

Comment: Thanks guys, i actually re-wrote my subclass as i was getting a little confused between what was going on in IB and in Code. So:
menuCell.textView.delegate = self; did actually work in setting the subviewed textfield delegate.

Comment: @poperob - I am having a similar issue and cannot get the UITextViewDelegate methods called when entering a field in a cell in a table.  How did you get this to work?  +1 for your question and I'll post a question and give you the points for answering.